# Transforming a data frame so that new columns are populated based on conditionals

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function, transform

I am working with a large data frame with many columns, some of which are used to calculate differences. The first two columns (Planning Cycle and Beneficiary) are identifier columns that are to be maintained. I want to transform the table below so that it no longer has the individual columns 'Total New_x', 'Applied_x', 'Planned_x' (and the corresponding _y columns), but new columns that will show only the amounts based on the value of the column 'variable'. For example (as seen below) in the first row, 'variable' = "dif_Total New", so the transformed data frame should have new 'Amount' columns that contain only the amounts from 'Total New_x' and 'Total New_y', respectively.

I am not sure if this requires a conditional statement or writing a function of some kind.

Turning this:

| Planning Cycle | Beneficiary | Total New_x | Applied_x | Planned_x | Total New_y | Applied_y | Planned_y | variable | Difference Magnitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | Sprite | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2627094 | 0 | 2627094 | dif_Total New | 2627094 |
| 2019 | Coke | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2627094 | 0 | 2627094 | dif_Planned | 2627094 |
| 2019 | Coke | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1406904 | 0 | 1406904 | dif_Total New | 1406904 |
| 2020 | Pepsi | 1222383 | 0 | 1222383 | 1222383 | 42148 | 1264531 | dif_Applied | 42148 |

Into this:

| Planning Cycle | Beneficiary | Amount 1 | Amount 2 | variable | Difference Magnitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | Sprite | 0 | 2627094 | dif_Total New | 2627094 |
| 2019 | Coke | 0 | 2627094 | dif_Planned | 2627094 |
| 2019 | Coke | 0 | 1406904 | dif_Total New | 1406904 |
| 2020 | Pepsi | 0 | 42148 | dif_Applied | 42148 |

Accompanying code for this:

```
compvars = ['Total New','Applied','Planned']
for var in compvars:
        difvar = 'dif_' + var
        varx = var + '_x'
        vary = var + '_y'
        df[difvar] = df[vary] - df[varx]

difvars = ['dif_' + var for var in compvars]
idvars1 = ['Planning Cycle', 'Beneficiary']
compvarsx = [var + '_x' for var in compvars]
compvarsy = [var + '_y' for var in compvars]
df = df[idvars1 + difvars + compvarsx + compvarsy]
df = df.melt(id_vars = idvars1 + compvarsx + compvarsy, value_vars = difvars, value_name = "Difference Magnitude")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
def fn(x):
    v = x["variable"].split("_")[-1]
    return pd.Series({"Amount 1": x[v + "_x"], "Amount 2": x[v + "_y"]})


df = pd.concat([df, df.apply(fn, 1)], axis=1)[
    [
        "Planning Cycle",
        "Beneficiary",
        "Amount 1",
        "Amount 2",
        "variable",
        "Difference Magnitude",
    ]
]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Planning Cycle Beneficiary  Amount 1  Amount 2       variable  Difference Magnitude
0            2019      Sprite         0   2627094  dif_Total New               2627094
1            2019        Coke         0   2627094    dif_Planned               2627094
2            2019        Coke         0   1406904  dif_Total New               1406904
3            2020       Pepsi         0     42148    dif_Applied                 42148
```